# iOS equivalent for addReactInstanceEventListener

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to listen for when the react context is initialised? It is possible in android like so:

```
final ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager = ((ReactApplication) getApplicationContext()).getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager();
ReactContext context = mReactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext();
// If it's constructed, send a notification
if (context != null) {    
}
else {
mReactInstanceManager.addReactInstanceEventListener(new ReactInstanceManager.ReactInstanceEventListener() {
public void onReactContextInitialized(ReactContext context) {                                             mReactInstanceManager.removeReactInstanceEventListener(this);
        }});
    }
```

Is this possible from the iOS Obj-C side?